# How to put multiple input boxes in a modal? wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Hi i am trying to put multiple text boxes into a modal, here is the code for one text box.

```
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(
            self, 'What is your favorite programming language?',
            'Eh??', 'Python')
```

Is there a way to put multiple text boxes in a modal?

Something like [this](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/C%20Sharp/MessageBox2.png) would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using the TextEntryDialog - you would have to create your own subclass of wx.Dialog and manually create your desired GUI elements in there.